Gallery Image After woocommerce_after_shop_loop
On my website, the front page is the WooCommerce shop page, and I'm trying to add an image gallery after the products are displayed.
I played around with different priorities (9,99,999,105 etc.) and also tried the woocommerce_after_main_content hook, but the image gallery is still showing above the products.
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'custom_woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 99 );

function custom_woocommerce_after_shop_loop(){
    echo do_shortcode('[Best_Wordpress_Gallery id=\u00228\u0022 gal_title=\u0022All images\u0022]');
}


Unfortunately no change. I really don't understand how it doesn't work.
